# Django calling url in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, redirect

I am doing my django project and I cannot find answer to how can I call my site from javascript function.

```
  var time = 5;
  setInterval(function() {
    if(time > 0) {
      document.getElementById("timecounter").innerHTML = "You will be redirected in "
      + time + " seconds. If not then ";
      time--;
    } else {
      location.href="{% url 'index' %}"
    }

  },1000)
```

this location.href redirects to wrong place. It literally puts "{% url 'index' %}" in URL.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Is this code used in a django-template?

Comment: Hi, this is in static/timecounter.js and I am calling this from my html

Comment: @chazefate Your template tag `{% url` (obviously) won't work unless it is used in a Django view/template. Use absolute URL of your site instead.

Comment: If this is a static file you can't use django syntax.

Comment: Hi, this is in static file. So is there any way that I can call like "request.get_host()"

Comment: You want to redirect to the root directory? Why don't you just use `/`

Comment: Well if I use this in heroku then it is not the best practice to change the location.href= "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"  to myapp.herokuapp.com. Or what do you think?

Comment: As @ilse2005 has said, you need to redirect to / or wherever index is.  Template tags are only interpreted by django when rendering a page.  Javascript is run in the browser, totally unrelated to django

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As your code is static and not processed by django, you can't use template tags. Change your code to this:

```
var time = 5;
  setInterval(function() {
    if(time > 0) {
      document.getElementById("timecounter").innerHTML = "You will be redirected in "
      + time + " seconds. If not then ";
      time--;
    } else {
      location.href="/" //this will redirect to your index
    }

  },1000)
```